# In Kubernetes, how to set pods' names when using replication controllers?

Tags: kubernetes

I have a simple replication controller yaml file which looks like this:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ReplicationController
metadata:
  name: nginx
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    app: nginx
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: library/nginx:3.2
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        name: nginx
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
```

And after running this replication controller, I will get 3 different pods whose names are "nginx-xxx", where "xxx" represents a random string of letters and digits.

What I want is to specify names for the pods created by the replication controller, so that the pods' name can be "nginx-01", "nginx-02", "nginx-03". And further more, for say if pod "nginx-02" is down for some reason, and replication controller will automatically create another nginx pod, and I want this new nginx pod's name to remain as "nginx-02".

I wonder if this is possible? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm also interested in this answer. To respond to "why would anyone need this", in my case we monitor using prometheus/grafana and we'd like to avoid building an infinite list of hostnames over time.

Answer (score 11):

You should be using statefulset instead of replication controllers. Moreover, replication controllers are replaced with ReplicaSets.

StatefulSet Pods have a unique identity that is comprised of an ordinal. For a StatefulSet with N replicas, each Pod in the StatefulSet will be assigned an integer ordinal, from 0 up through N-1, that is unique over the Set. Each Pod in a StatefulSet derives its hostname from the name of the StatefulSet and the ordinal of the Pod.

StatefulSets matches your requirements and hence use it in your deployment.

Try the deployment files below:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nginx
  labels:
    app: nginx
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 80
    name: web
  clusterIP: None
  selector:
    app: nginx
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: web
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx # has to match .spec.template.metadata.labels
  serviceName: "nginx"
  replicas: 3 # by default is 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx # has to match .spec.selector.matchLabels
    spec:
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 10
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: k8s.gcr.io/nginx-slim:0.8
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
          name: web
        volumeMounts:
        - name: www
          mountPath: /usr/share/nginx/html
      volumes:
      - name: www
        emptyDir:
```

Answer (score 10):

This can be implemented using [statefulsets](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/) which is out of beta since version 1.9.  Quoting the documentation: When using `kind: StatefulSet`,

> Pods have a unique identity that is comprised of an ordinal, a stable network identity, and stable storage. The identity sticks to the Pod, regardless of which node it’s (re)scheduled on.
>
> Each Pod in a StatefulSet derives its hostname from the name of the StatefulSet and the ordinal of the Pod. The pattern for the constructed hostname is `$(statefulset name)-$(ordinal)`.

So in the example above, you would get `nginx-0`,`nginx-1`,`nginx-2`

Answer (score 5):

If you're running stateless workloads, I cannot imagine why you would want to have fixed identities associated with each object if your intention is to run N replicas of a particular pod.

There is no way to do this using a ReplicaSet/ReplicationController. When the controller creates new pods, it will have a generated name suffix after the pod name.

If that is what you really want (fixed identity/ordinal index), the property is satisfied by the [StatefulSet resource](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/#pod-identity) which is stable since Kubernetes v1.9. However, it also comes with additional guarantees that you probably do not need.

Comment: For example, I'd like to make my pods be aware of the FQDN names that they are accessible on. Right now, a pod cannot even determine its IP address from the env vars (e.g. 10-42-25-26.dev.pod.cluster.local), as it seems.
The background of this requirement would be building a monitoring solution (like Hystrix/Turbine dashboard).

Converting stateless pods into StatefulSets just to fulfil the above goal seams to be a hack.

Comment: avoid using environment variables as that was meant for backward compatibility with old released of docker that have the link feature, it is deprecated now. host, port environment variables would require you do things in order. best to expose the pods as a service, default pattern pods are part of a replicaset and that replica set exposed as a service and cluster DNS will always dynamically point to the right clusterip address and update fdqn as in service.namespace.svc.cluster.local or what ever cluster default base name you have overridden